# R Markdown: how to have a list next to an inserted image

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

How can I insert an image and place it next to a list in Markdown? I have a loop of length n. At every iteration I need to output a list and an inserted image next to each other. On the next iteration I do the same, but the on the following row.

I know how to insert the images in a loop:

````
```{r myplots,results="asis"}
for (i in 1:n) {
  pic_name <- paste("\n![](",paste(i,".png",sep=""),sep="")
  pic_name <- paste(pic_name,")\n",sep="")
  cat(pic_name)
}
```
````

But how could I for example insert this list next to the images

```
Here's a list:

- an item in the list
- another item
- yet another item
```

Comment: Hi hi, you might want to check out the tufte package which contains a sample Rmd showing how to create Tufte like doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating an html table and assigning the list to one of the two columns and the image to the other one:

```
cat("<table><tr valign='top'><td>")
cat(LIST)
cat("</td>")
cat("<td>")
cat(pic_name)
cat("\n</td>")
cat("<tr></table>")
```

where the list and the image are aligned at the top.